# Android Expand expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to to implement ExpandableListView under TabHost...tab works well and list also generate but when i go to ExpandList clicking on GroupItem,this not work...

how can i implement this...

my code is here....

```
public class Setting extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, null);
     expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);






        prepareListData();       

     // preparing list data
    // 

     listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

     // setting list adapter
     expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


     expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                 int groupPosition, long id) {
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
             // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return false;
         }
     });

     // Listview Group expanded listener
     expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

         @Override
         public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });

     // Listview Group collasped listener
     expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

         @Override
         public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     });

     // Listview on child click listener
     expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                 int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(
                     getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : "+ listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                     childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             return false;
         }
     });



     return v;
     }


    private void prepareListData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Battery Remaining");
        listDataHeader.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        listDataHeader.add("Set Alarm Tone");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
```

My list not expand.....help me plz...

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and stepping thru it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement OnGroupClickListener interface in your ExpandableListAdapter and override
the following methods :

```
onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) ;
    onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in layout android:focusable="false"
and           android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to all clickable item like,Button,ImageButton of the 
row layout..